# Proof of Inscribed circle in Right angle triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Question asks to

> Prove the diametre of a circle inscribed in a right angle triangle is equal to the sum of the two shorter sides minus that of the hypotheneus

I was able to create a diagram (like the one below) and attempted to create as many congruent triangles as I could with the right angle triangle's sides so I could find some way to prove them similar in some way to the radius but I have been unable to link them. Can you please help?

[image: With the image ignore the numbers and listings they are irrelevant to the question]

With the image ignore the numbers and listings they are irrelevant to the question. Just here as a reference

Comment: This follows from inspection.  Using your picture:  The hypotenuse is $7-2r$.  The sum of the two legs is $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That diagram basically does that. The sum of the two legs of the triangle
minus the hypotenuse is
\begin{align}
&BD+CD+CE+EA-BF-FA\\
&=BD+CD+CE+EA-DB-EA\\
&=CE+EA=DO+OE=2r.
\end{align}

Comment: In your second line of proof do you mean BD instead of DF? And in your 3rd CD instead of EA?

Comment: Anyway I understand what you meant, I can't believe I overlooked that, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

$AB = AF + FB$

$BC = BD + DC = FB + r$

$CA = CE + EA = r + AF$

$BC + CA = 2r + AF + FB = 2r + AB$

Diameter = $2r = BC + CA - AB$

Answer (score 0):

$AB=5$ in the other hand $$AB=(3-r)+(4-r)$$so $$5=7-2r\\r=1$$

Comment: With the image ignore the numbers and listings they are irrelevant to the question. Just here as a reference for my diagram